# Recuperar valores de Mysql con PHP y JS en Ventana Modal Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, mysqli

Buenas noches, trataba de llenar una ventana modal con valores de campos de tabla, con **jquery**, y recupera todos los campos excepto los 3 últimos y no veo porque. Estos son los archivos: la ventana modal **html**, el archivo **jquery** para llenar y el botón que acciona la ventana.

```js
  $('#alumUpdate').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var matricula = button.data('matricula') 
    var id = button.data('id') 
    var nombre = button.data('nombre')
    var apellidos = button.data('apellidos') 
    var curp = button.data('curp') 
    var genero = button.data('genero') 
    var grupo = button.data('grupo')
    var semestre = button.data('semestre')
    var taller = button.data('taller')
    var status = button.data('status') 
    var beca = button.data('beca')   
    var correo = button.data('correo')
    var direccion = button.data('direccion')
    var nombreTut = button.data('nombreTut')  
    var apeTut = button.data('apeTut')
    var telTut = button.data('telTut')
    
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Modificar Alumno: '+matricula)
    modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(id)
    modal.find('.modal-body #matricula').val(matricula)
    modal.find('.modal-body #nombre').val(nombre)
    modal.find('.modal-body #apellidos').val(apellidos)
    modal.find('.modal-body #curp').val(curp)
    modal.find('.modal-body #genero').val(genero)
    modal.find('.modal-body #grupo').val(grupo)
    modal.find('.modal-body #semestre').val(semestre)
    modal.find('.modal-body #taller').val(taller)
    modal.find('.modal-body #status').val(status)
    modal.find('.modal-body #beca').val(beca)
    modal.find('.modal-body #correo').val(correo)
    modal.find('.modal-body #direccion').val(direccion)
    modal.find('.modal-body #nombreTut').val(nombreTut)
    modal.find('.modal-body #apeTut').val(apeTut)
    modal.find('.modal-body #telTut').val(telTut)
    $('.alert').hide();
  })
```

```html
<form id="actualizarAlum">
<div class="modal fade" id="alumUpdate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modificar Alumnos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="datos_ajax"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="matricula" class="control-label">Matrícula:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="matricula" name="matricula" required maxlength="18">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id">
          </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre" class="control-label">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" required required="45">
          </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="apellidos" class="control-label">Apellidos:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" required required="45">
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="curp" class="control-label">CURP:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="curp" name="curp" required required="25"> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="genero" class="control-label">Genéro:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="genero" name="genero">
                <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option> 
                <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option> 
            </select>   
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="grupo" class="control-label">Grupo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="grupo" name="grupo" required maxlength="15">
       </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="semestre" class="control-label">Semestre:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="semestre" name="semestre" required maxlength="15">
          </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="taller" class="control-label">Taller:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taller" name="taller" required maxlength="15">
          </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="status" class="control-label">Status:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
                <option value="Irregular">Irregular</option>
            </select>   
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="beca" class="control-label">Beca:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="beca" name="beca" required maxlength="15">
          </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="correo" class="control-label">Correo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo" required maxlength="18">
       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="direccion" class="control-label">Dirección:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" required maxlength="37">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombreTut" class="control-label">Nombre Tutor:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreTut" name="nombreTut" required maxlength="26">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="apeTut" class="control-label">Apellido Tutor:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apeTut" name="apeTut" required maxlength="30">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telTut" class="control-label">Teléfono Tutor:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telTut" name="telTut" required maxlength="15">
       </div>
       
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlAl)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['matricula'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['apellidos'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['curp'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['genero'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['idGrupo'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Semestre'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>

             <td>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alumUpdate" data-id="<?php echo $row['idAlumno']?>" data-matricula="<?php echo $row['matricula']?>" data-nombre="<?php echo $row['nombre']?>" data-apellidos="<?php echo $row['apellidos']?>" data-curp="<?php echo $row['curp']?>" data-genero="<?php echo $row['genero']?>" data-grupo="<?php echo $row['idGrupo']?>" data-semestre="<?php echo $row['Semestre']?>" data-taller="<?php echo $row['idTaller']?>" data-status="<?php echo $row['status']?>" data-beca="<?php echo $row['idBeca']?>" data-correo="<?php echo $row['correo']?>" data-direccion="<?php echo $row['direccion']?>" data-nombreTut="<?php echo $row['nombreTutor']?>" data-apeTut="<?php echo $row['apellidos_tutor']?>" data-telTut="<?php echo $row['tel_tutor']?>"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' ></i> Modificar</button>
```

Comment: si solo es un modal, puedes hacer que lo printe el PHP directamente en vez de cargarlo en html. Si los datos deben ser dinamicos si, necesitaras jquery, pero hazlo con Ajax en vez de cascarle los valores tal que así. hmtl - Clicar en boton con ID -> php consultar resultados + devolver respuesta -> jquery rellenar datos en html. Saludos

Comment: Puede que no tengas valor en los tres ultimos y por eso no te aparezcan, o que el formato sea distinto o no admita valor predefinido (o lo intentes hacer de un modo equivoco). Recargar los datos de un formulario como valores predefinidos de un input esta bien. Meter los datos en un TD... bueno, digamos que hace diez años que no se usa.

Comment: valores en la tabla de mysql si hay, pero es extraño, porque tienen los mismos nombres, justo por eso deje los mismos para cada archivo.
Gracias Saludos

Comment: usa fetch array en vez de fetch assoc y printa todas las posiciones a ver si es verdad que hay o no...

Comment: probaré, muchas gracias saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifica los siguiente datos:

```
var nombreTut = button.data('nombretut')  
var apeTut = button.data('apetut')
var telTut = button.data('teltut')
```

**jQuery** al procesar los **"data attributes"** los convierte a todos a **minúsculas**

Comment: no lo sabia, probaré, muchas gracias saludos

Comment: tenias razón creo que erá por eso. muchas gracias, saludos